# Average number of comparison for 3 items

Tags: sorting, comparison

[image]

What is the average number of comparisons performed when sorting 3 items?

The question is based on the above picture.

Comment: The answer is fairly obvious from the comparison tree. What are you missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are six possible orderings of three numbers. You can distinguish between six states with two 2-bit codes and four 3-bit codes; that is the lower bound if all orderings are equally likely. Average number of bits = 2 2/3rds.

Since you can’t have arbitrary tests but only comparisons between two items, you won’t be able to achieve the lower bound for larger numbers of items.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined what you mean by *average*, so let me assume that the average is taken over all permutations of some fixed array consisting of three *distinct* numbers (the exact numbers don't matter, since the result will be the same).

Denote the number of comparisons performed on an array $A$ by $C(A)$. Then the average number of comparisons is
$$
\frac{C(1,2,3) + C(1,3,2) + C(2,1,3) + C(2,3,1) + C(3,1,2) + C(3,2,1)}{6}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

> $$\frac{2\cdot 2+4\cdot 3}6.$$